# Convention for wrapping errors in Golang

Tags: go, error-handling

When wrapping errors in golang, should the `%w` verb be used at the beginning or at the end when creating the new error? Or it doesn't matter because there's no convention or recommendation - we can use whatever makes the error string easier to understand?

Eaxample when `%w` is used at the end:

```
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("decompress %v: %w", name, err)
}
```

And an example when `%w` is used at the beginning:

```
if record.BoatSize != 0 {
    err = fmt.Errorf("%w: boatSize is set", ErrInvalidBoatRecord)
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's any official convention or style guide, but if you search for `"%w` in the std lib you get back a lot less results than when you search for `%w"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The position of `%w` is not used when wrapping , nor when unwrapping the error, so it does not matter.

Use whichever makes your error message clearer.

Usually adding it to the end is more common, it reads well when chaining the errors, going from general to more specific errors. For example:

> IO error: file open error: file does not exist: example.txt